# How to solve the problem of OpenVAS not starting in Kali?

Tags: kali-linux

My OpenVAS isn't starting in Kali Linux.

```
root@kali:~# openvas-mkcert
One or more files do already exist and would be overriden:
   /var/lib/openvas/CA/cacert.pem
   /var/lib/openvas/private/CA/cakey.pem
   /var/lib/openvas/CA/servercert.pem
   /var/lib/openvas/private/CA/serverkey.pem
You need to remove or rename them and re-run openvas-mkcert.
If you run openvas-mkcert with '-f', the files will be overwritten.
root@kali:~# openvas-nvt-sync
[i] This script synchronizes an NVT collection with the 'OpenVAS NVT Feed'.
[i] The 'OpenVAS NVT Feed' is provided by 'The OpenVAS Project'.
[i] Online information about this feed: 'http://www.openvas.org/openvas-nvt-feed.html'.
[i] NVT dir: /var/lib/openvas/plugins
OpenVAS feed server - http://www.openvas.org/
This service is hosted by Intevation GmbH - http://intevation.de/
All transactions are logged.

Please report synchronization problems to openvas-feed@intevation.de.
If you have any other questions, please use the OpenVAS mailing lists
or the OpenVAS IRC chat. See http://www.openvas.org/ for details.

[i] Feed is already current, no synchronization necessary.
root@kali:~# openvas-mkcert-client -n om -i
Generating RSA private key, 1024 bit long modulus
...++++++
.......................++++++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [DE]:State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:Locality Name (eg, city) []:Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:Common Name (eg, your name or your server's hostname) []:Email Address []:Using configuration from /tmp/openvas-mkcert-client.3524/stdC.cnf
Check that the request matches the signature
Signature ok
The Subject's Distinguished Name is as follows
countryName           :PRINTABLE:'DE'
localityName          :PRINTABLE:'Berlin'
commonName            :PRINTABLE:'om'
Certificate is to be certified until May 19 17:49:55 2016 GMT (365 days)

Write out database with 1 new entries
Data Base Updated
Your client certificates are in /tmp/openvas-mkcert-client.3524 .

You will have to copy them by hand.

root@kali:~# openvasmd --rebuild
root@kali:~# openvasmd --backup
root@kali:~# openvasad -c 'add_user' -n openvasadmin -r
bash: openvasad: command not found
root@kali:~# openvasad -c 'add_user' -n openvasadmin -r admin
bash: openvasad: command not found
root@kali:~# openvassd
root@kali:~# openvas-mkcert
One or more files do already exist and would be overriden:
   /var/lib/openvas/CA/cacert.pem
   /var/lib/openvas/private/CA/cakey.pem
   /var/lib/openvas/CA/servercert.pem
   /var/lib/openvas/private/CA/serverkey.pem
You need to remove or rename them and re-run openvas-mkcert.
If you run openvas-mkcert with '-f', the files will be overwritten.
root@kali:~# openvas-mkcert -f

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            Creation of the OpenVAS SSL Certificate
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

This script will now ask you the relevant information to create the SSL certificate of OpenVAS.
Note that this information will *NOT* be sent to anybody (everything stays local), but anyone with the ability to connect to your OpenVAS daemon will be able to retrieve this information.


CA certificate life time in days [1460]: 
Server certificate life time in days [365]: 
Your country (two letter code) [DE]: PL
Your state or province name [none]: 
Your location (e.g. town) [Berlin]: Wroclaw
Your organization [OpenVAS Users United]: 







-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            Creation of the OpenVAS SSL Certificate
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Congratulations. Your server certificate was properly created.

The following files were created:

. Certification authority:
   Certificate = /var/lib/openvas/CA/cacert.pem
   Private key = /var/lib/openvas/private/CA/cakey.pem

. OpenVAS Server : 
    Certificate = /var/lib/openvas/CA/servercert.pem
    Private key = /var/lib/openvas/private/CA/serverkey.pem

Press [ENTER] to exit

root@kali:~# openvas-nvt-sync
[i] This script synchronizes an NVT collection with the 'OpenVAS NVT Feed'.
[i] The 'OpenVAS NVT Feed' is provided by 'The OpenVAS Project'.
[i] Online information about this feed: 'http://www.openvas.org/openvas-nvt-feed.html'.
[i] NVT dir: /var/lib/openvas/plugins
OpenVAS feed server - http://www.openvas.org/
This service is hosted by Intevation GmbH - http://intevation.de/
All transactions are logged.

Please report synchronization problems to openvas-feed@intevation.de.
If you have any other questions, please use the OpenVAS mailing lists
or the OpenVAS IRC chat. See http://www.openvas.org/ for details.

[i] Feed is already current, no synchronization necessary.
root@kali:~# openvas-mkcert-client -n om -i
Generating RSA private key, 1024 bit long modulus
.............................++++++
..++++++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [DE]:State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:Locality Name (eg, city) []:Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:Common Name (eg, your name or your server's hostname) []:Email Address []:Using configuration from /tmp/openvas-mkcert-client.3871/stdC.cnf
Check that the request matches the signature
Signature ok
The Subject's Distinguished Name is as follows
countryName           :PRINTABLE:'DE'
localityName          :PRINTABLE:'Berlin'
commonName            :PRINTABLE:'om'
Certificate is to be certified until May 19 17:59:47 2016 GMT (365 days)

Write out database with 1 new entries
Data Base Updated
Your client certificates are in /tmp/openvas-mkcert-client.3871 .

You will have to copy them by hand.

root@kali:~# openvasmd --rebuild
root@kali:~# openvassd
bind() failed : Address already in use
root@kali:~#
```

This is not working:

```
[i] This script synchronizes an NVT collection with the 'OpenVAS NVT Feed'.
[i] The 'OpenVAS NVT Feed' is provided by 'The OpenVAS Project'.
[i] Online information about this feed: 'http://www.openvas.org/openvas-nvt-feed.html'.
[i] NVT dir: /var/lib/openvas/plugins
OpenVAS feed server - http://www.openvas.org/
This service is hosted by Intevation GmbH - http://intevation.de/
All transactions are logged.

Please report synchronization problems to openvas-feed@intevation.de.
If you have any other questions, please use the OpenVAS mailing lists
or the OpenVAS IRC chat. See http://www.openvas.org/ for details.

@ERROR: max connections (200) reached -- try again later
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1534) [Receiver=3.0.9]
[e] Error: rsync failed.
[i] This script synchronizes a SCAP data directory with the OpenVAS one.
[i] SCAP dir: /var/lib/openvas/scap-data
[i] Will use rsync
[i] Using rsync: /usr/bin/rsync
[i] Configured SCAP data rsync feed: rsync://feed.openvas.org:/scap-data
OpenVAS feed server - http://www.openvas.org/
This service is hosted by Intevation GmbH - http://intevation.de/
All transactions are logged.

Please report synchronization problems to openvas-feed@intevation.de.
If you have any other questions, please use the OpenVAS mailing lists
or the OpenVAS IRC chat. See http://www.openvas.org/ for details.

@ERROR: max connections (200) reached -- try again later
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1534) [Receiver=3.0.9]
[e] Error: rsync failed. Your SCAP data might be broken now.
[i] This script synchronizes a CERT advisory directory with the OpenVAS one.
[i] CERT dir: /var/lib/openvas/cert-data
[i] Will use rsync
[i] Using rsync: /usr/bin/rsync
[i] Configured CERT data rsync feed: rsync://feed.openvas.org:/cert-data
OpenVAS feed server - http://www.openvas.org/
This service is hosted by Intevation GmbH - http://intevation.de/
All transactions are logged.

Please report synchronization problems to openvas-feed@intevation.de.
If you have any other questions, please use the OpenVAS mailing lists
or the OpenVAS IRC chat. See http://www.openvas.org/ for details.

@ERROR: max connections (200) reached -- try again later
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1534) [Receiver=3.0.9]
Error: rsync failed. Your CERT data might be broken now.
Stopping OpenVAS Manager: openvasmd.
Stopping OpenVAS Scanner: openvassd.
```

And, the terminal freezes at this point.

```
Starting OpenVas Services
Starting Greenbone Security Assistant: ERROR.
Starting OpenVAS Scanner: ERROR.
Starting OpenVAS Manager: ERROR.
root@kali:~#
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You don't seem to have applied any analysis. You've ignored the messages from the software (at least twice). https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/

Comment: VTC as the user isn't registered on U&L and they ignored several significant error messages shown in the question's transcript

Answer (score 0):

Try :

Navigate to /etc/init.d/openvas-server and openvas-manager and add time to this line:

```
# time to wait for daemons death, in seconds
# don't set it too low or you might not let openvassd die gracefully
DODTIME=5
```

make that DODTIME something like 15 or 20 for both openvas-server and openvas-manager.

start your scanner:
service openvassd start
then start the manager with the --rebuild argument.
openvasmd --rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Openvasd, openvas-server or(if you have no typo there) openvassd should be using similar sources so i thing you already have a service running there. Try to stop running services;

```
sudo service openvas-server stop
sudo service openvasd stop
sudo service openvassd stop
```

Then you can run the necessary command i believe.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue for along time in various different variations. 
I've found a distro upgrade or upgrade fixes it sometimes but this will work as well.

```
apt-get purge --auto-remove redis-server

apt-get install openvas

openvas-setup
```

will work and you don't lose any history.